# How to provide an asynchronous RESTful API wrapping a synchronous API

Tags: python, api, http

We're creating a web service (RESTful API) in Django. Our API will wrap both our own internal data as well as some other APIs that our web services layer will be accessing.

One of the APIs we're using has some long-running calls that don't return an HTTP response for on the order of a minute. The API has a separate API call to get status of the current operation, but that means that the user has to initiate the long-running operation, then have a separate process poll for status. We don't want our API to work that way, we want the initial request to just return a response that says that it's in progress.

So what we want to do is when we get a long-running request, we kick off an HTTP request of our own to the API asynchronously, then return a response. Then every time we get a status poll we just pass that through and respond with the response we got. When we get the callback that the operation is complete, then the next time we get a status poll we'll just respond that the operation is complete and return the data. This means that we'll need handlers for incoming status requests to check the list of in-progress long-running requests to respond with the status.

Does this seem like a reasonable way to approach this?  Which python libraries we should be looking at to make this sort of thing easier? We're not sure whether to go with something low-level like eventlet or twisted, or something a little heavier-weight like celery. Celery seems to be the normal recommendation for this sort of thing, but I'm not 100% sure what its place would be.

Thanks,
Spencer

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation a couple of months ago, probably you already solved your problem, but for other person facing the same situation I'll post what I did at that time.

Basically I used the http://www.celeryproject.org/ library, dispatching in a asynchronous way a long running operation returning a successful HTTP response the celery job id, the asynch operation would register the status and job id in a sqlite database (was enough for what I was doing), and a client was querying (using rest) the status of the job.